# Unit testing touch events in react native

Tags: tdd, ecmascript-6, react-native, jestjs

I am trying to test drive react native code using [this](http://www.schibsted.pl/2015/10/testing-react-native-components-with-jest/) guide. The react native is overridden by reactjs to enable shallow rendering and testing using jestjs.

Even though I am able test shallow rendered components (checking its presence and children), I am unable to test touch events.

```
handleTouch() {
 this.setState({ showDescription: !this.state.showDescription });
}


render() {
const description = this.state.showDescription ? (<Text style={styles.description}>{this.props.entry.description}</Text>) : null;
return (
  <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() => this.handleTouch()}>
    <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
      <View style={styles.row}>
      </View>
      {description}
    </View>
  </TouchableNativeFeedback>
 )
}
```

I'm trying to test if on touch of `TouchableNativeFeedback`, `description` tag is rendered. The reactjs [TestUtils](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#simulate) provides `Simulate` but it didn't work.

This is my spec setup:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    profileView = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<ProfileEntryView entry={entry}/>);
    var touchableNativeFeedback = TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(profileView, TouchableNativeFeedback);
    TestUtils.Simulate.onTouchEnd(touchableNativeFeedback);
});
```

How will I test UI interactions using reactjs `TestUtils` for react-native?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because ReactTestUtils simulate does not have `onTouchEnd` or `onPress` event. So you need to add to mock object `mocks/react-native.js`:

```
const NativeComponent = (type) => {
    return React.createClass({
        render() {
            var properties = {className: type};
            if (typeof this.props.onPress !== 'undefined') {
                properties.onClick = this.props.onPress;
            }
            Object.assign(properties, this.props);
            return (
                <div {...properties}>{this.props.children}</div>
            );
      }
};
...
ReactNative.TouchableNativeFeedback = NativeComponent("TouchableNativeFeedback");
```

And update your test code to:

```
var touchableNativeFeedback = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(profileView, 'TouchableNativeFeedback');
TestUtils.Simulate.click(touchableNativeFeedback);
```

Looking for more code [from this page](http://www.apentle.com/react-native-testing-component-action#testing-component).